# Creating a boolean to find a different kind of travel cup

Tags: java, boolean

Prompt: Many TravelCups do not have handles. To allow for this add a boolean instance variable to the TravelCup class. Change your constructors and methods to accommodate this change. Add any appropriate methods to the class this change requires. Demonstrate that changes work in your test runs.

I was able to do most of the project, but I get stuck here. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to create a new class or create a new object, but I've tried creating a new constructor and that just gives me an error. I've hit a dead-end and now I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
    public class Cup
{
    // instance variables 
    private int volume; // in oz.
    private String color;
    private String material;

    /**
     * Default Constructor for objects of class Cup
     */
    public Cup()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        volume = 8;
        color = "white";
        material = "ceramic";
    }
    
    public Cup(int v, String c, String m)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        volume = v;
        color = c;
        material = m;
    }
    
    public Cup(Cup other)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        volume = other.volume;
        color = other.color;
        material = other.material;
    }
    
    public void set(int v, String c, String m)
    {
        volume = v;
        color = c;
        material = m;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "This is a " + color + " cup made of " + material
                + "\nIt holds " + volume + " oz. ";
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return    the volume
     */
    public int getVolume()
    {
        return volume;
    }
    
    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }
    
    public String getMaterial()
    {
        return material;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Cup other)
    {
        if(other == null)
            return false;
        else if( getClass() != other.getClass())
            return false;
        else
        {
            Cup otherCup = (Cup)other;
            return volume == otherCup.volume && color.equals(otherCup.color) && material.equals(otherCup.material);
        }
    }
}


public class LogoCup extends Cup
{
    private String logo;
    private String slogan;

    public LogoCup()
    {
        super( );
        logo = "";
        slogan = "";
    }
    
    public LogoCup(int v, String c, String m, String lg, String s)
    {
        super(v, c, m );
        logo = lg;
        slogan = s;
    }
    
        public LogoCup(LogoCup other)
    {
        super(other );
        logo = other.logo;
        slogan = other.slogan;
    }

        public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString()
                + " Logo: " + logo + " Slogan: " + slogan;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(LogoCup other)
   {
       if(other == null)
        return false;
       else if( getClass() != other.getClass())
        return false;
       else
       {
           LogoCup otherLogoCup = (LogoCup)other;
           return logo.equals(otherLogoCup.logo) && slogan.equals(otherLogoCup.slogan) && super.equals( otherLogoCup);
       }
    } 
    
    
    public String getLogo()
    {
        
        return logo;
    }
    
        public String getSlogan()
    {
        return slogan;
    }
}



public class TravelCup extends LogoCup
{
    public TravelCup()
    {
        super();
    }
  
    
    public TravelCup(int v, String c, String m, String lg, String s)
    {
        super(v, c, m, lg, s );

    }
    
        public TravelCup(TravelCup other)
    {
        super(other );
    }

 
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Travel Cup! " + super.toString() + "\nEvery TravelCup has a lid!";
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
       if(other == null)
            return false;
       else if( getClass() != other.getClass())
            return false;
       else
        {
            TravelCup otherTravelCup = (TravelCup)other;
            return super.equals( otherTravelCup);
        }
    } 
    
    public boolean equals(Object handle);
    {
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Where is your TravelCup class? You've shown us Cup.

Comment: I would have made handle optional in Cup; have you ever seen the tea cup from a really old Japanese tea set?

Comment: You're on the right track. In the same way that LogoCup adds a member variable containing the logo, TravelCup needs to add one indicating whether or not it has a handle. Can you try to do that and update your question?

Comment: @NomadMaker TravelCup is there, scroll down.

Comment: Please edit the code and make an [mre]. For instance, was LogoCup needed at all?

Comment: @tgdavies thank you, I will try that and then get back to you.

Comment: @NomadMaker Hi, I think the LogoCup class was needed to understand as the TravelClass is inheriting all of its information. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TravelCup` may be implemented with the following updates:

- added field `boolean hasHandle`, its getter and setting via constructors
- updated constructors to use existing constructors using `this(...)`
- updated `toString` and `equals` to include new field
- (optional) added `set` method to set all parameters via call to `super.set` that needs to be added to `LogoCup`

```java
class TravelCup extends LogoCup {
    private boolean hasHandle = false;
    
    public TravelCup() {
        super();
    }
  
    public TravelCup(int v, String c, String m, String lg, String s) {
        this(v, c, m, lg, s, false);
    }
    
    public TravelCup(int v, String c, String m, String lg, String s, boolean h) {
        super(v, c, m, lg, s );
        this.hasHandle = h;
    }

    public TravelCup(TravelCup other) {
        super(other);
        this.hasHandle = other.hasHandle;
    }
 
    public String toString() {
        return "Travel Cup! " + super.toString() + ", hasHandle? " + hasHandle + "\nEvery TravelCup has a lid!";
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if(other == null)
            return false;
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if(getClass() != other.getClass())
            return false;
        TravelCup otherTravelCup = (TravelCup) other;
        return super.equals(otherTravelCup) && this.hasHandle == otherTravelCup.hasHandle;
    } 
    
    public boolean hasHandle() {
        return hasHandle; 
    }
    
    public void set(int v, String c, String m, String l, String s, boolean h)
    {
        super.set(v, c, m, l, s);
        this.hasHandle = h;
    }
}

// class LogoCup
class LogoCup extends Cup {
// ...
    public void set(int v, String c, String m, String l, String s) {
        super.set(v, c, m);
        logo = l;
        slogan = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: pokey war, please make sure that you understand the code you use. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the encouraging words. Thankfully with your advice, I was able to come up with a solution similar to Alex Rudenko's before he posted his. I just wasn't sure as to how to update. Alex's code did help me with the "public boolean equals" section as I did get stuck there. So I greatly appreciate everyone's help here.